# rails is processing trash html codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the rails form helper code,

```
    <%= form_tag({ :action => "create"}, :method => "POST", :id=>"login") do  -%>

    <h1>Log In</h1>
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <%= text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Username', :autofocus=>true%>

        <%= password_field_tag :userpass, params[:userpass], placeholder: 'Password', id:'password'%>


    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
        <a href="/registration/index">Register</a>
    </fieldset>

    <% end %>
```

and this is the html code, what i want,

```
<form action="/login/create" method="post" id="login" >
        <h1>LogIn</h1>
        <fieldset id="inputs">

        <input id="username" type="text" name ="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>

        <input id="password" type="password" name="userpass" placeholder="Password" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" name="apply">
        <a href="/registration/index">Register</a>
        </fieldset>

        </form>
```

However, if i run the rails code, it makes the code like this,

```
<input id="username_{:placeholder=&gt;&quot;Username&quot;, :autofocus=&gt;true}" name="username[{:placeholder=&gt;&quot;Username&quot;, :autofocus=&gt;true}]" size="30" type="text">
```

Somebody knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `text_field_tag` in your form, not just `text_field`:

```
<%= form_tag({ :action => "create"}, :method => "POST", :id=>"login") do  -%>

  <h1>Log In</h1>
  <fieldset id="inputs">
    <%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username], { :placeholder => 'Username', :autofocus => true } %>

    <%= password_field_tag :userpass, params[:userpass], placeholder: 'Password', id:'password'%>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="actions">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
      <a href="/registration/index">Register</a>
  </fieldset>

<% end %>
```

You should also look into [field_set_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-field_set_tag) - that may save you some headaches if you're expecting to use the HTML `fieldset` tag.

Comment: Thank you. But now it makes a code like this. <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="{:placeholder=&gt;&quot;Username&quot;, :autofocus=&gt;true}">

Comment: Edited - you need to give a `value` for `text_field_tag`, then the options hash.